# need help with iphone movable button?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

does anyone know what component this app is using???

[image]

I know it use uipagecontrol to control the page
but i don't know what they use to control the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably using three20's `TTLauncherView` control or they might of made their own version of it

More info:  http://three20.info/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can move any UIView, and a `UIButton` is a UIView subclass. Just set its `frame` property.